# External IP address in samba share logs

Tags: samba

I have a samba share with debian jessie and everything works fine. But in the logs file I get attempts from external ip. I have checked and I don't have any ports opened. I don't know what could it be, and I am worried that I have some security issues.

It's a wifi modem-router. The lan is set up with IP 192.168.1.1 and
subnet mask 255.255.255.0 (dhcp for all devices except for the samba share which has a static ip). The samba server requires a user/password (no guest) and you can read and write.

Comment: What do you mean for EXTERNAL? What's your network design? Does it mean you have an internal interface which the share is available?

Comment: I edited the question with the design. The samba share works fine, and from the lan I can read write. What I am afraid of is that someone from outside the lan (that what I mean by external) can download or upload files from the samba server.

Answer (score 1):

Does your internet service come through a router?  Most home routers have a web interface which you can only access from inside your network.  Use your web browser and the router's IP address as the URL.  For example:

```
http://192.168.1.1/
```

You'll need a username and password, which may be printed on a sticker on the router.  Or google "*default verizon router username password*" or similar.

Once you're in, click on "*Firewall Settings*" or similar.  Mine has a "*Security Log*" menu item that shows what inbound traffic was accepted or blocked.

From there you should be able to setup rules to block traffic by port or by other features.

Comment: Yes, it is through a router, and I have the username / password. The log was disabled by default, and as far as I am concerned port 139 and 445 are not open